# extending contiki for semantic reasoning

Tags: contiki

I am new to Contiki-OS. Although I have experience in java but not very strong background in C/C++. I am working on a Wireless sensor networking domain in which I have to develop an application which can run in Contiki-OS, this application is already developed in java but as contiki is based on C/C++ so i have to port application from java to C.

*I hope this edit makes the question clear*

Answer (score 2):

The best places to start are:

http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki

Comment: i have a java library which i want to use in my application which i will be using in contiki coap simultions. is there a way to create this application without porting the whole library to C/C++

Comment: Contiki runs on microcontrollers, which cannot really run JVM.

Comment: i am using contiki-os to simulate some motes which would have semantic capabilities. As the contiki-os (erbium) is written in C but our semantic libraries are written in java. can you guide me if it is possible to exploit these libraries in erbium or contiki-os. or i have to rewrite everything from scratch.

Comment: @hasanalikhattak the answer is that most likely you will need to rewrite it, if you wish to run that on a physical node. If it's all avbout simulation, you can take a look into Cooja, which is a Java simulator. However I'm not entirely sure if Cooja is even remotely related to what you are asking.